# Optimize query with Eloquent (count on big table)

Tags: laravel

I have an administration panel and in it I display all the users, with a line that mentions how many photos he has posted.

By default I have a seeder that imports 17,000 photos and the user who posts them is an administrator, so I have 1 user who has 17,000 photos.

In this panel, I display this count:

```
{{ $user->pictures()->count() }}
```

However with the debug bar I see that it takes a lot of time (300ms), here is the query with the debug bar:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `pictures` where `pictures`.`user_id` = 'fe9eaf79-fc2d-47b8-8a43-4c61a81bce22' and `pictures`.`user_id` is not null and `status` = 1 and `pictures`.`deleted_at` is null
```

In the controller, I've this :

```
public function show()
    {
        $users = User::orderBy('username', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(20);

        return view('admin.users', [
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

Do you know how I can optimize this count on such a big table?

Comment: 300ms is a good time. do you need to decrease it more ?

Comment: show us the funtion() first please

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I've edited the post, this is what you want ?

Comment: According to the pages, I have at most 1 second of request, it is times which remain suitable? that seems to me nevertheless high, I would just like to know if it is possible to better optimize a count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Eager Loading**

```
 $users = User::with('pictures')->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(20);
```

Or if you just need the count `withCount` so that each user will have a property called `pictures_count`.Then use it in blade like `{{ $user->pictures_count }}`

```
 $users = User::withCount('pictures')->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(20);
```

Check this video also from [LaravelDaily](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bi2bEXBa9Ko)

Also check these pull requestes as well .There are many ways you can increase your performance.

[LaravelDaily
/
Laravel-Challenge-Movie-Table-Eloquent](https://github.com/LaravelDaily/Laravel-Challenge-Movie-Table-Eloquent/pulls)

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the n+1 problem.

What's happening is that for every user, Laravel is making another query (`$user->pictures()->count()`), so the more user you are displaying, the longer the load time will be.

You can use eager loading to load the number of pictures for each users within your first query.

```php
$users = User::query()
         ->withCount('pictures')
         ->orderBy('username', 'ASC')
         ->paginate(20);
```

The number of pictures will then be available on each user by doing `$user->pictures_count`.